# Circular (modulus) representation of the complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am wondering if there exists a different presentation of the complex number where the imaginary line from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ for a given real part $x$ of $z=x+iy$ is represented by the circumference of the circle whose radius is $x$.
[image]

In the figure, the new plane (to the right) is a transformation of the ordinary complex plane with all $y$s lines are represented by the circumference of the circles whose radius are $x$s. In other words, the $y$-coordinate is now the angle-$mod-N$ where N=$2\pi x$ and $x$ is the radius.

For example, the point $z=5+i4$ is now represented by a point on the circumference of the circle with $r=5$ and located at $4$ Mod (N) where N is $2\pi (5)$.

Comment: You could do this, but you won't get anything nicer than the standard polar form from a complex analytic point of view

Comment: You are asking for a polar form where $r=x$ and $\theta = y.$ The problem is that this isn't a unique representation except in the strip of radius $2 \pi.$ You could scale $y$ coordinate by, e.g., $\arctan$ to get uniqueness, but points will get very squished together. I've seen this done with $\mathbb{R}^2$ a lot, but because you are not preserving the complex structure very nicely, you should not expect nice analytic properties. When working with holomorphic $f$ remember that $\Re f$ and $\Im f$ are not themselves holomorphic - i.e., you want things expressed via $z,$ not $x4 and $y$

Comment: Suppose there is sine-wave along the imaginary line (x= x0 ) of the complex plan. Because of the homomorphism I just described in the question, the wave is now wrapped around a circle of radius= x0. Normally the circle have radius =1 with a circumference $2\pi$ in order to sync with the period of the wave. Now if this wave is the wave-function of the quantum mechanics and if the radius is ½ instead of $1$ then the ground state energy level of the harmonic oscillator will be $1/2 h\omega$ which is exactly what is calculated by the quantum mechanics.

Comment: On the other hand, the circle with radius ½ corresponding to the critical line in the Riemann hypothesis where all non-trivial zeros of Riemann zeta function located. No wonders why there are lots of speculations about the link between the Riemann hypothesis and the energy levels of the harmonic oscillator according to the quantum mechanics.